# Reading a client's header from Python CGI script?

Tags: python, cgi, http-headers

I'm writing a very simple web service, written in Python and run as CGI on an Apache server.

According to Python docs (somewhere... I forgot where), I can use sys.stdin to read the data POSTed by a random client, and this has been working fine. However, I would like to be able to read the HTTP header information as well - incoming IP, user agent, and so on. I'd also like to keep it very simple for now, by using only Python libraries (so no mod-python). How do I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are running as a CGI, you can't read the HTTP header directly, but the web server put much of that information into environment variables for you.  You can just pick it out of os.environ[]

The list of environment variables that might be there is pretty long.  You can find it by doing a web search for "common gateway interface".  For example, in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875.txt they are called "meta-variables".

Answer (score 15):

These are given to the CGI script through the environment:

```
import os
user_agent = os.environ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
ip = os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Answer (score 5):

As [this page](http://htmlhelp.com/faq/cgifaq.2.html) explains, most HTTP request headers are made available to your CGI script via environment variables.  Run [cgi.test()](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.test) instead of your script to see the environment (including HTTP request headers) shown back to your visiting browser.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I capture in Python 3 from CGI (A) URL, (B) GET parameters and (C) POST data:

=======================================================

import sys, os, io

## CAPTURE URL

myDomainSelf = os.environ.get('SERVER_NAME')

myPathSelf = os.environ.get('PATH_INFO')

myURLSelf = myDomainSelf + myPathSelf

## CAPTURE GET DATA

myQuerySelf = os.environ.get('QUERY_STRING')

## CAPTURE POST DATA

myTotalBytesStr=(os.environ.get('HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH'))

if (myTotalBytesStr == None):

```
myJSONStr = '{"error": {"value": true, "message": "No (post) data received"}}'
```

else:

```
myTotalBytes=int(os.environ.get('HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH'))

myPostDataRaw = io.open(sys.stdin.fileno(),"rb").read(myTotalBytes)

myPostData = myPostDataRaw.decode("utf-8")
```

## Write RAW to FILE

mySpy = "myURLSelf: [" + str(myURLSelf) + "]\n"

mySpy = mySpy + "myQuerySelf: [" + str(myQuerySelf) + "]\n"

mySpy = mySpy + "myPostData: [" + str(myPostData) + "]\n"

## You need to define your own myPath here

myFilename = "spy.txt"

myFilePath = myPath + "\" + myFilename

myFile = open(myFilePath, "w")

myFile.write(mySpy)

myFile.close()

=======================================================

Here are some other useful CGI environment vars:

AUTH_TYPE

CONTENT_LENGTH

CONTENT_TYPE

GATEWAY_INTERFACE

PATH_INFO

PATH_TRANSLATED

QUERY_STRING

REMOTE_ADDR

REMOTE_HOST

REMOTE_IDENT

REMOTE_USER

REQUEST_METHOD

SCRIPT_NAME

SERVER_NAME

SERVER_PORT

SERVER_PROTOCOL

SERVER_SOFTWARE

=================================

I am using this methods on Windows Server with MIIS and Python 3 in CGI mode.