# Get current URL from browser using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, browser, geturl

I am running an HTTP server which serves a bitmap according to the dimensions in the browser URL i.e `localhost://image_x120_y30.bmp`. My server is running in infinite loop and I want to get the URL any time user requests for BITMAP, and at the end I can extract the image dimensions from the URL.

The question asked here:

[How to get current URL in python web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468862/how-to-get-current-url-in-python-web-page)

does not address my problem as I am running in infinite loop and I want to keep on getting the current URL so I can deliver the requested BITMAP to the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current URL in python web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468862/how-to-get-current-url-in-python-web-page)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If to use Selenium for web navigation:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print (driver.current_url)
```

Comment: I am running python 2.7 and I got following error
ImportError: No module named selenium
@Andersson

Comment: Selenium compatible with 2.7 as well as with 3.4.
You need to install this package first and then import it within code. Try 

pip install selenium

Comment: it is now working but it opens a new browser window of firefox , what I want is to get the url from browser.

Comment: You can access page of required site with `driver.get('put_your_site_name')` and then get page url with `driver.current_url` after each loop iteration
P.S. Please put more info about how your script works/should work or just show the part of existed code

Comment: currently I am getting the requested content by parsing the HTTP request but I want if it is possible to get the url directly form browser so I can parse it to get the requested BITMAP dimensions.

Comment: I'm using chrome and I a getting `data:,` with `self.driver.current_url`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current url by doing
`path_info = request.META.get('PATH_INFO')
http_host = request.META.get('HTTP_HOST')`.
You can add these two to get complete url.
Basically request.META returns you a dictionary which contain a lot of information. You can try it.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a class problem similar to this.
We've been using Splinter to walk through pages (you will need to download splinter and Selenium).  As I walk through pages, I periodically need to pull the url of the page I'm currently on.  I do that using the command  new_url = browser.url  Below is an example of my code.

I do this using the following code.

```
##import dependencies
from splinter import browser
import requests


## go to original page 
browser.visit(url)

## Loop through the page associated with each headline
for headline in titles:
    print(headline.text)
    browser.click_link_by_partial_text(headline.text)
## Now that I'm on the new page, I need to grab the url
    new_url = browser.url
    print(new_url)
## Go back to original page
    browser.visit(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I use in Django.

For eg.,. if browser url is https://www.example.com/dashboard

```
try:
    from urlparse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse

frontend_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
url = urlparse(frontend_url)
print (url)
# ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='example.com', path='/dashboard', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hello you can use below code in order to achieve URL from open browser
    
    import os
    import webbrowser
    import pyperclip
    import time
    import keyboard
    import pygetwindow as gw
    import pyautogui
    
    @app.route("/")
    def redirect_to_authorization():
        redirect_url = f"https://www.google.com"
        webbrowser.open(redirect_url)
        time.sleep(5)
        browser_window = gw.getActiveWindow()
        browser_window.activate()
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'l')
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
        keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl + c')
        time.sleep(0.5) 
        url = pyperclip.paste()
        print(url)
        # os.system("taskkill /f /im chrome.exe")
        index = url.find('code=')
        if index != -1:
            code = url[index + len('code='):]
            print("Code:", code)
        # os.system("taskkill /f /im chrome.exe")
        return {"Token" : code}

# Or you can use below code too

    @app.route("/CodeTwo")
    def redirect_to_authorization():
        redirect_url = f"https://www.google.com"
        webbrowser.open(redirect_url)
        time.sleep(5)
        active_window = gw.getActiveWindow()
        if active_window is not None:
            title = active_window.title
            if " - Google Chrome" in title:
                # Extract the URL from the title
                url = title.split(" - Google Chrome")[0]
                return {"Token" : url}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -7):

You could use the `requests` module:

```
import requests


link = "https://stackoverflow.com"
data = requests.request("GET", link)
url = data.url
```

Comment: This solution doesn't answer what he needs. It also has errors as you passed _url_ instead of variable _link_ as parameter to request.