# Automatically print network data from FireBug or browser debug console using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, debugging, firefox, firebug

Is where any way to get network data from browser's debug console or firebug to python script automatically, simultaneously? Webbrowser opens some websites and I see only simple, short URL. Instead of URL with params etc. All this data I may found in debug console manually, but how can I reach it using python and selenium?

Comment: Are you using `driver.current_url`? This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479290/get-current-url-from-browser-python

Comment: driver.current_url does not show me what I want.