# How to read url on active tab of browser

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 but am not able to get anything how to read url which are active in tab of browsers.

So far i tried this

```
import win32gui
import win32process
import psutil
#w=win32gui
#value=w.GetWindowText(w.GetForegroundWindow())
#print(value)
appwindow = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
ProcessID = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(appwindow)
#procname = psutil.Process(ProcessID)
#applicname = procname.name()
print("hello")
```

Comment: If you are using Selenium for programmatic browsing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30479543/5161222

Comment: The task is i have to do it without selenium only using python code 2.7.

Comment: perhaps something like this, then? https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2010-November/010910.html

Comment: i have code in c#, can you help me in converting this in python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp/18983677 this one

Comment: @Benjamin let me try

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Windows OS so I won't be able to help debug with windows-specific code

Comment: No problem main thing is to have python code which gives current url of browser

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pybrinf](https://github.com/manucabral/pybrinf) package, is Windows supported and allows you to get some info about a browser.